# Overloading << (Error with code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this overload for the << operator. Visual studio tells me that I have to many parameters. Node is a structure if that helps.

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const node* &obj )
{
    strm << "ItdID: " << obj.itemId << "\nItem Description: " << obj.itemDescription << "\nItem Quanity: " << obj.quanity 
         << "\nWholesale Cost: $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << obj.wholesale << "\nRetail Cost: $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << obj.retail;
    return strm;
}
```

Comment: Where is this code located? As a member function? It needs to be a free function: move it outside of the class.

Comment: Try using `->` rather than `.` on that *pointer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const node* &obj )` as a `friend` function to your `node` class.

So inside your node class you will have

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const node* &obj );
```

and then in your cpp file you will have

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const node* &obj )
{
    strm << "ItdID: " << obj.itemId << "\nItem Description: " << obj.itemDescription << "\nItem Quanity: " << obj.quanity 
         << "\nWholesale Cost: $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << obj.wholesale << "\nRetail Cost: $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << obj.retail;
    return strm;
}
```

This should fix your bug.

Comment: @user3304124 If my answer solved your problem please accept it as the correct answer by clicking the accept button(the check mark).

Comment: I just did the edit but now I have two types of errors. One saying that my itemId must have class/struct/union. (THis goes for the four others in my output) and another error I guess is lined to the previous one saying that expression must have class type.

Comment: Just eliminated the second type of error.

Comment: Use the -> operator on obj not the . It is a pointer even though you are passing it by reference

Comment: Thank you once again. Clicking the accept mark now.